# Github desktop client says that a folder is pushed but files are missing

Tags: git, github

I have a folder that contains about 200 datafiles that are used by a script and I want to have the whole thing on github for a lab that I will teach next week. Now I tried uploading it via the desktop client, and it says that it managed to do it, but I do not see the files on the website.

Is there some limit that I am hitting perhaps?

Comment: can you try with command line to go in the directory where you have your files and do a `git branch`, followed by a `git status`, followed by a `git remote -v`and post here some results? (maybe directly in your question, so is more visible to everyone)

Comment: Also please confirm if by doing `git remove -v` the result URLs for `origin` are the one that matches your repository online (the GitHub website url of your repo) where you expect to see the files.